# How can I use an array item with Interlocked.CompareExchange

Tags: c#, interlocked

I'm familiar with using `Interlocked.CompareExchange()` with plain objects. However I'd like to use it with the member of an array:

```
string[] myArray = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" }; 
string myStr = (string) Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref myArray[0], null, myArray[0]); 
// myArray[0] == null
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: And what problem are you having with that solution?

Comment: Well, everything looks good to me. Ran your code and is perfectly fine. I am not sure if I see where you need help.

Comment: I really misunderstood my original error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using it like this

```
string[] myArray = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
        string myStr = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref myArray[0], "F", myArray[0]);
        foreach (var item in myArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
```

And this is the out put

```
F B C
```

Everything is Fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem. You are setting the first string in the array to null. And that's why it's null. This is how you use it:

```
string[] myArray = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" }; 
string myStr = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref myArray[0], "ASDF" /* VALUE */, 
myArray[0]); 
//myArray[0] == "ASDF"    <- VALUE YOU SET
```